# key modifier Ctrl breaks Drag and Drop in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, drag-and-drop

I am following [this](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/platform-api-reference/xml/daily-docs/libqt4/dnd.html) example given by Qt to implement DnD. It currently drags and drops until I press a modifier key like `Ctrl` or `Shift`.

The weird part is when I try to debug using a break point in VS 2010 it starts to work when I resume until a key modifier is pressed again.

What am I doing wrong and how can I stop modifier keys from breaking DnD?

Comment: What happens when a modifier key is pressed? Please share some code reproducing the problem.

Comment: When a modifier key is pressed I can not drag and drop. As for code I'm following the example i link to. I'll try putting a small example here later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I have has nothing to do with my code. It seems the same issue exist with the drag and drop demo provided by Qt 4.8.2.

Answer (score 0):

Over 10 years later, I have been searching for an answer to a related problem. It seems to me that it makes a difference whether you push and hole the CTRL or SHIFT key before you start the drag. Then it sets the mode for move or copy. But if you change the key state after starting the drag, it seems to be ignored. So for consistent results always choose the key state before starting the drag. (My experience is mostly on Linux.)

I don't know if this has anything to do with the original question, but it might.